# VBA - Workbooks.Open() does not work because repaird file

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very much into programming and learning be doing.

I am desperate with this issue:
I can open the workbook the normal way when I use the mouseklick but with VBA Workbooks.Open() it doesen't perform the task.
I figured out that it tries to open the file but because it needs to perform some repair it doesn't open with VBA.

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)                 'doesnt work 
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName, ReadOnly:=True) 'doesn't work
Set wb = Workbook.Open(fileName, CorruptLoad:=1)  'doesn't work 
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName, CorruptLoad:=2) 'it opens but the file is then 
                                                  ' unrepaired with meaningless content
```

Is there a another way so that the workbooks opens with vba like clicking on it?

Thank you very much for any help

Best,
Robert

want to have the workbook open and continue the code to run

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Have you tried manually repairing the file? (Opening, repairing and then re-saving?)

Comment: Hello, I do get an error message: Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

Comment: and I have to go through numerous excels to open and perform a task and close again like 1000s

Comment: ps. the errors I don't know exactly what the root cause for the problem. The repair it performs is the following: Repaired Data: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml-Part etc.

Comment: I couldn't progress any further. The fallback option would be to open all files manually by clicking on the respectiv excel file, which would be extremely timeconsuming doing this for approx 5000 workbooks. Isn't there a solution to this? I would be very grateful for any help